# How to create popup's for dynamic tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

**Html**

```
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>


<!--To display JSON data in the tables-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script> $(function() {
    var dmJSON = "data.json";
    $.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {
        $.each(data.records, function(i, f) {
            var $table="<table  class='mystyles' table border=5><tbody><tr>" + "<td>" + f.Clue + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>" + f.Answer + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>" + f.Status + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td> " + f.Views + "</td></tr>" + "</tbody>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</table>"
            $("#entrydata").append($table)
        });
    });
});

<!--Popup function-->
             $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
               <div id="popup-box1" class="popup-position">
        <div id="popup-wrapper">
            <p style="text-align: right;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popup-box1');">X</a></p>
            <div id="popup-container">
                <h3>Popup box 1</h3>
                <p>A popup box</p>
            </div><!-- Popup container end -->
            <p style="text-align: right;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" >Close popup box</a></p>
        </div><!-- Popup wrapper popup end -->
    </div><!-- Popup box 1 end -->


        <!--Creating a dynamic table-->
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popup-box1');">
              <div class="wrapper" >
                    <div class="profile">
                      <div id='entrydata' >

                        </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
          </div>
```

The code creates tables dynamically and displays JSON data. I have added a pop up but the problem is i need different pop-up window for each table. For ex: For the first table i want popup 1, second table should display popup 2. Since these tables are dynamically created i don't know how to add different popup's to it. Any solution to this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of providing the code dump, do provide the code in issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign unique ID's to the table like this.

```
<!--To display JSON data in the tables-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script> $(function() {
                     var dmJSON = "data.json";
                     $.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {
                         var idx=1;
                         $.each(data.records, function(i, f) {
                             var myid = 'mytable'+String(idx);
                             idx++;
                             var $table="<table  id='"+myid+"' class='mystyles' table border=5><tbody><tr>" + "<td>" + f.Clue + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>" + f.Answer + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td>" + f.Status + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><td> " + f.Views + "</td></tr>" + "</tbody>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</table>"
                             $("#entrydata").append($table)
                         });

                     });
                 });
```

Comment: Okay. Should i write it as a separate function or within the json function ?

Comment: @LorettaV Updated the code in my answer, just replace your block of code with this one.

Comment: with this code, your tables will have id of mytable1, mytable2, mytable3, etc.. so you can assign specific popups.  if you need to dynamically generate the popups as well,  just use the same format.

Comment: This code works, but can you explain in detail as i am new to this subject. Should i add pop up data in the html file or in a json file ? because now i have few tables later more tables will be added

Comment: Sure, can you click the checkmark next to my answer to indicate it is correct and also the up arrow.  Thanks :)   As far as adding the popup data, just do whatever is easiest.  I think both ways will work fine.

Comment: Bascially what i did was create a variable and assign it a value of 1.  Then as it went the .each() loop, it would create a table name by typecasting that variable to string and assigning it to another variable.  var myid = 'mytable'+String(idx);  and then increment that variable by one in each loop idx++;  You then insert the variable as your tables ID when creating it.   You can do the same thing when creating popups if you are doing them with json.  you can check the value on the end with myid.slice(-1)  (note, that will only work for the first 9 tables, then you would need slice(-2))

Comment: Actually if the id's are like mytable1, mytable2, mytable3, etc.. you can use myid.slice(8) and that will give you everything after mytable which will be the number.   If your tables are tab1, tab2, tab3, etc.. you would use .slice(4)  just +1 the length of the word in front of the number.